# Can Razor pages go in any other directory then Pages?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

With the new Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core, if the `Pages` folder *special*, like the `Controllers` folder is or can one configure it to use another directory?

I'm not suggesting that I'd want to, just trying to understand the framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can change it, absolutely. You can use `AddRazorPagesOptions` to configure this. e.g:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(opt => {
        opt.RootDirectory = "/SomeRoot"
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

One can also use `WithRazorPagesRoot(string)` as so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .WithRazorPagesRoot("/Foo");
}
```